# Roots Acorn: Error: 'acorn' is not a registered wp command. (Docker WP CLI Container (wordpress:cli-php8.2))

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm encountering a problem where my wp cli doesn't recognize the acorn package.

Objective: I aim to develop a WordPress plugin using the acorn package (https://roots.io/acorn/docs/installation/).

I have also posted this question on the roots forum : https://discourse.roots.io/t/error-acorn-is-not-a-registered-wp-command-docker-wp-cli-container-wordpress-cli-php8-2/26453

Environment: I'm operating within a docker container, utilizing the "wordpress:cli-php8.2" docker image for WordPress cli. The docker image setup is fine, and I can use the wp cli tool without issues.

Additionally, I've installed the following package into the image for debugging purposes and to have composer available for the Acorn installation.

```bash
RUN apk update && \    
    apk add shadow && \
    apk add sudo && \
    apk add composer && \
    apk add nano && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

I attempted to install Acorn in a few ways with no success:

1. Executed "composer require roots/acorn" within the plugin folder, but it was unsuccessful.
2. Ran "composer require roots/acorn" at the root of the wp installation, , but it was unsuccessful.

To test I attempted the following variations of the command.
`wp acorn --allow-root --path=/var/www/html`
`wp acorn --allow-root --path=/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_dir`
`wp acorn --allow-root`

but received the...
error: 'acorn' is not a registered wp command.

I verified if the package was recognized by wp cli using
`wp package list --allow-root` and found it wasn't.

So, I tried the following:

3. Executed `wp package install roots/acorn  --allow-root`. This just ran a composer install in the wp cli's packages directory, which can be located by running: `wp --info --allow-root`, This caused `wp package list --allow-root` to claim the package was install but did not result in the command `wp acorn` being recorgnised.
4. Finally I attempted to install acorn globally via `composer global require roots/acorn`.

I've also run the composer post-dump-autoload script and the standard dump autoload.

Despite all attempts, I cannot seem to get the wp cli to recognize the 'acorn' command.

Comment: Seems the roots founder has a bit of a senior dev complex as seen (https://discourse.roots.io/t/error-acorn-is-not-a-registered-wp-command-docker-wp-cli-container-wordpress-cli-php8-2/26453), I had a response and they want me to make the wordpress root install composer managed with all it's dependencies installed in the root vendor of the wp install none of which is mentioned in the docs. I'll update this post if I have any luck. Doesn't seem you can simple have acorn and wp cli running isolated within a plugin of wp or even have the two running globally without altering the wp install itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to add a comment (that this should be), but Ben in the Roots discourse is correct that you are not using Acorn within a composer managed wordpress setup.

Just adding a composer.json within a normal wordpress file system, does not make it a composer-managed installation.

You should read up a little bit on how to do it (for example https://deliciousbrains.com/storing-wordpress-in-git/) or you could use premade packages like Bedrock. It is worth the time investment.

To answer your question: Unless you follow some guide that will actually allow you to have a composer driven installation, you will not be able to use Acorn.